# MissingResourceException when a module A receives a module B class and do a getBundle() on it, with the classloader of this B class

Tags: java, module, java-10

During a long time I used a class named *Anomaly* that was used by my business objects to return any business error or warning that they detected on themselves by some quick auto-checking. "*I'm a City that have no population, no density of population...*".

I developped a core class in a maven module, that from a parameter key and some arguments, eventually called a getBundle function to use its result and send the warning/error message :

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle(businessObject.getClass(), Locale.getDefault(), businessObject.getClassLoader());
```

Since Java 10 (I didn't experienced Java 9) came, I stored this maven module in a Java module :

```
module A {
   exports myPackageA;
}
```

And I have now this trouble : I have a business object class in a module B, that uses A, in case of anomaly.

```
module B {
   exports myPackageB;
   requires myPackageA;
}
```

But when

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle(businessObject.getClass(), Locale.getDefault(), businessObject.getClassLoader());
```

is now called in the module A, given a class from the module B, it is not able to find the expected resource bundle. And it ends by a *MissingResourceException*, and my programs fails as soon as I compile them, at test time.

What is the correct way to do things now ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: ResourceBundle works as before when you deploy the bundles on the class path. If you migrate bundles to modules then it does require some changes. The "Resource Bundles and Named Modules" in the ResourceBundle javadoc provides the options. The javadoc for Java SE 11 has been further expanded and is a good reference.